# How to understand pipeline built with Grep and Sed

Tags: shell, sed, grep

## Example

I'm trying to understand below line of **shell** code.

```
   grep "^1  " file0 | grep -v MODEL | sed 's/./&E/86' | sed 's/./&  /8' | sed 's/./&  /20' > file1
```

## Question

Could someone explain what this pipeline does?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```sh
# Add "E" after the 86th character
sed 's/./&E/86'

# Add "  " after the 8th character
sed 's/./&  /8'

# Add "  " after the 20th character
sed 's/./&  /20'
```

Comment: Where's the behaviour of the 86, 8, 20 documented?

Comment: For GNU sed, [here](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html#The-_0022s_0022-Command); for POSIX sed, [here](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/sed.html)

Comment: The answer is in the online documentation ([The `s` Command](http://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html#The-_0022s_0022-Command)); it is not present in the GNU man page information.  The `info sed` does cover it: _NUMBER Only replace the NUMBERth match of the REGEXP._ and it is covered in the POSIX spec for [`sed`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/sed.html)too.

Comment: @StevenPenny: didn't think so; why?  I was genuinely asking the question (I'd not seen the notation in use before).  I found the answer to my comment/question but it took longer than the 5 minutes to edit my original comment.  It looks like I should have tuned my second comment a bit more; it was intended as a continuation to my original question/comment rather than anything else.  If you want me to remove it, I will.

Comment: So at the end this is the answer right? I am still confuse actually the complete line is longer.

Comment: @StevenPenny: the stuff that gets me is the options added recently (for sake of argument, this millennium rather than the last).  Since the basics don't change, you can get a very long way with a thorough knowledge of what also worked in the 80s and 90s.  But there are new features that I don't always know about; the number after the `s///` expression was one such feature.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler in fairness the gnu man page does say: `This is just a brief synopsis of sed commands to serve as a reminder to those who already know sed; other documentation (such as the texinfo document) must be consulted for fuller descriptions`

Answer (score 6):

Instead of using multiple `grep` pipelines before `sed`, you could combine it all into one `sed` expression

```sh
sed '/^1  /{/MODEL/b;s/./&E/86;s/./&  /8;s/./&  /20}' file0 > file1
```

Comment: Or more simply with some delete operations: `sed -e '/^1  /!d' -e '/MODEL/d' -e 's/./&E/86' -e 's/./&  /8' -e 's/./&  /20'` (Note: I divided into separate arguments, since `;` is a non-portable extension).